# Accessing array elements using the associative index and numbered index

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to define an array where I can access the elements via their string and numeric index?

Comment: I think this is what you're saying.  Creating an array like so: `array('a'=>'x', 'b'=>'y', 'c'=>'z')`, and accessing `'b'` with `$array[1]` (since it's the second index).  Is that right?

Answer (score 7):

`array_values()` will return all values in an array with their indices replaced with numeric ones.

http://php.net/array-values

```
$x = array(
    'a' => 'x',
    'b' => 'y'
);
$x2 = array_values($x);

echo $x['a']; // 'x'
echo $x2[0]; // 'x'
```

The alternative is to build a set of by-reference indices.

```
function buildReferences(& $array) {
    $references = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $references[] =& $array[$key];
    }
    $array = array_merge($references, $array);
}

$array = array(
    'x' => 'y',
    'z' => 'a'
);

buildReferences($array);
```

**Note that this should only be done if you're not planning on adding or removing indices.**  You can edit them though.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this.

```
$arr = array(1 => 'Numerical', 'two' => 'string');
echo $arr[1]; //Numerical
echo $arr['two']; //String
```

Comment: Not even close to the right answer. You're printing two different elements both with differnt type indexes.

Comment: @roger Maybe if you explained more clearly what you're after, you'd get better quality answers.

Answer (score 3):

PHP allows a mixture of string and numeric-indexed elements.

```
$array = array(0=>'hello','abc'=>'world');

echo $array[0]; // returns 'hello'
echo $array['0']; // returns 'hello'
echo $array['abc']; // returns 'world';
echo $array[1]; // triggers a PHP notice: undefined offset
```

A closer look at the last item `$array[1]` reveals that it is not equivalent to the 2nd element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

martswite's answer is correct, although if you've already got an associative array it may not solve your problem. The following is **an ugly hack** to work around this - and should be avoided at all cost:

```
$a = array(
'first' => 1,
'second' => 2,
'third' => 3
 );
 $b=array_values($a);

 print $b[2];
```